# Using Ubuntu 12.04 + Apache 2.4 + Php 5.5 : WebDav Possible

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, php5, apache-2.4

I had ubuntu 12.04 LTS + Apache 2.4 + PHP 5.4 installed via ondrej packages.
I upgraded to PHP 5.5, and it seems now impossible to launch webdav extension for apache.

The apache mod webdav can't be upgraded :

```
Depends: apache2.2-common (>= 2.2.4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

Does anyone had any luck with this kind of configuration ? I can't find out any repository/package for webdav to solve my problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Please see if your repo matches : `ppa:ondrej/apache2`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to akash's comment, I see that I was missing `ppa:ondrej/apache2` in my repositories

So :

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

did the trick and saved my day.